# railsのname errorの原因について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

現在railsにてkaminariを使用してpagenation機能を作るのにcontrollerに以下のエラーが発生して調べてもわからないので質問しました。

```
NameError in PageController#index
uninitialized constant PageController::Page
Extracted source (around line #4):
```

```
def index
    @page = Page.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
    end
```

エラーと言われているのは@page = Page.allの部分ですがこのエラーは単に文字の間違いなのでしょうか?それともviews/page/index内の記述に間違いがあるのでしょうか？

発生の流れとしては

1. rails g controller page index
2. page controller.rbを上記に書き換える。
3. views/page/index.html.erbを作成
4. rails sにて3000/page/indexをするとエラー

ちなみに3のindex内は下記

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>単語一覧</h1>
</div>
<div class="list-group">
  <% @pages.each do |page| %>
    <%= link_to(word, class: 'list-group-item') do %>
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
        <%= word.word %>
      </h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">
        <%= page.reading %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= paginate @pages %>
</div>
```

どなたかエラー発生原因のご教授よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score -1):

view側では <% @pages.each do |page| %> となっているので、Controller側の変数名を@pagesに変えたら動くと思います。

```
def index
-   @page = Page.all
+   @pages = Page.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
    end
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。